# How to test CSRF

Tags: spring-security, csrf

I am using Spring framework 3.2 and Spring Security 3.2 in my application. I have implemented CSRF in custom login form and in some other forms to protect against web threats. But now I have to test that custom login form and other pages are CSRF protected. How can I test it?
Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Firefox you can download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Go to the custom login form for example. In Firebug, find the CSRF field and change the value. Submit the form. If you get a forbidden message, you have successfully verified CSRF protection.